# mysql SUM column on WHERE condition

Tags: mysql, sum

Im trying to get a total sum of all the columns that meet a condition. Here is my current setup

```
    SELECT 
                      COUNT(order_type = 'BUY') AS buy_fill,
                      COUNT(order_type = 'SELL') AS sell_fill,
                      SUM(btc_total) AS fill_sum
                      FROM fill_orders
                      WHERE coin_id = '$coin'
                      AND time_stamp >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 55 SECOND)
```

This is what I have now and its counting how many types of buy and sell orders I have and is also giving me sum of all orders but I need to the break the sum of the orders into BUY orders and SELL orders.

Heres the code that I'm trying trying to make work.  I've added (btc_total WHERE order_type = 'BUY') and  SUM(btc_total WHERE order_type = 'SELL')

```
      SELECT 
                            COUNT(order_type = 'BUY') AS buy_fill,
                            COUNT(order_type = 'SELL') AS sell_fill,
                            SUM(btc_total) AS fill_sum,

                            SUM(btc_total WHERE order_type = 'BUY') AS buy_total
                            SUM(btc_total WHERE order_type = 'SELL') AS sell_total
                      FROM fill_orders
                      WHERE coin_id = '$coin'
                      AND time_stamp >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 55 SECOND)
```

Comment: `GROUP BY order_type`? Add this to your original statement, not your new one

Comment: Doing this you'd also want to collapse the two `COUNT` rows in to the single line `COUNT(order_type) as fill`

Comment: Well I still need the COUNT as Im using that data. I just need to expand on my query and break the fill_sum into BUY and SELL totals as right now the fill_sum  is a combination of both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"conditional aggregates" conventionally contain a `case expression`

```
SELECT
      COUNT(CASE WHEN order_type = 'BUY' THEN order_type END)      AS buy_fill
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN order_type = 'SELL' THEN order_type END)     AS sell_fill
    , SUM(btc_total)                                               AS fill_sum
    , SUM(CASE WHEN order_type = 'BUY' THEN btc_total ELSE 0 END)  AS buy_total
    , SUM(CASE WHEN order_type = 'SELL' THEN btc_total ELSE 0 END) AS sell_total
FROM fill_orders
WHERE coin_id = '$coin'
AND time_stamp >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 55 SECOND)
```

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```
SUM(btc_total WHERE order_type = 'BUY') AS buy_total
```

to this:

```
SUM(IF(order_type='BUY',btc_total,NULL)) AS buy_total
```

The MySQL `IF()` function evaluates the first argument as a boolean, if that's TRUE, it returns the second argument, else it returns the third argument.

The `IF()` will be evaluated for each row, and the return from that expression will get totaled up by the SUM() aggregate.

or, use the more ANSI-standard equivalent to achieve the same result:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN order_type = 'BUY' THEN btc_total END) AS buy_total
```

---

This pattern is commonly referred to as "conditional aggregation".

For the "counts" we can replace `COUNT` with `SUM`, like this:

```
SUM(order_type = 'BUY') AS buy_fill
```

MySQL evaluates the equality comparison as a boolean, which returns 1, 0 or NULL, which are then totaled up by the SUM aggregate. (A COUNT of that would include zeros and ones, not just the ones.)

The above is equivalent to

```
SUM( CASE
     WHEN order_type  = 'BUY' THEN 1
     WHEN order_type <> 'BUY' THEN 0
     ELSE NULL
     END
   ) AS buy_fill
```

If we want to use a `COUNT` aggregate, we could do it like this:

```
COUNT(IF(order_type = 'Buy',1,NULL)) AS buy_fill
```

(We could use any non-null value in place of `1`, and get an equivalent result.)